# how to create genesis block on ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

`geth --datadir ./ init customgenesis.json`

Fatal: Failed to read genesis file: open customgenesis.json: no such file or directory

Comment: Do you have the `customgenesis.json` in same directory as your console directory? if not, provide proper path to it.

Comment: how to find customgenesis.json in ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

In order to start a network you need to have a genesis file. This genesis file will be having details about the accounts in the network, difficulty of the block, network id , chain id etc. Copy the below config and save it a file with ".json"

```
{
  "alloc": {
  "0xe2138366adc7bae0b41d205e7d0ba8fadadd8e33": {
  "balance": "99999999999999999"
   }
},
"config": {
  "chainId": 15,
  "homesteadBlock": 0,
  "eip155Block": 0,
  "eip158Block": 0
},
"coinbase": "0xe2138366adc7bae0b41d205e7d0ba8fadadd8e33",
"difficulty": "0x20000",
"extraData": "","gasLimit":"0x2fefd8",
"nonce":"0x000000000001fd4e",
"mixhash":
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash":
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp":"0x00"
}
```

then, use the following command in the directory you have saved that file and then initialize a network with that genesis file

```
geth --datadir="." init fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the file `customgenesis.json`.

You can create a custom genesis file using the wizard from the puppeth tool.

You can download it at https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ (Geth & Tools)